# Unable to register an ONNX model in azure machine learning service workspace

Tags: azure, onnx, azure-machine-learning-service

I was trying to register an ONNX model to Azure Machine Learning service workspace in two different ways, but I am getting errors I couldn't solve.

**First method: Via Jupyter Notebook and python Script**

```
model = Model.register(model_path = MODEL_FILENAME,
                       model_name = "MyONNXmodel",
                       tags = {"onnx":"V0"},
                       description = "test",
                       workspace = ws)
```

The error is : **HttpOperationError: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Service invocation failed!Request: GET https://cert-westeurope.experiments.azureml.net/rp/workspaces'**

**Second method: Via Azure Portal**
[image: Error: Create model "MyONNXmodel": ajax error 413.]

Anyone can help please?

Comment: Your code looks fine to me (works on my account!). For the ajax error code in Portal, have you tried a smaller model?

Comment: Thank you @DavideFiocco, I have a specific model that I need to use so I can't get it smaller.

Answer (score 0):

error 413 means the payload is too large. Using Azure portal, you can only upload a model upto 25MB in size. Please use python SDK to upload models larger than 25MB.

Comment: Any idea what the max limit for a model file size is to register from local? I am trying to register a 900 mb model with the AZ CLI and it times out. I suppose I have to mount it on a blob store?