# How can I register in Azure ML Service a machine learning model trained locally?

Tags: python, azure, deployment, azureportal, azure-machine-learning-service

I am trying out [Azure Machine Learning Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/machine-learning-service/) for ML deployment.

I have already trained a model on a compute VM and saved it as pickle, and now would like to deploy it (I am using Python on Azure notebooks for the purpose as of now).

From the [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/service/tutorial-train-models-with-aml#register-model), it looks like I need to I need a `run` object to be existing in my session to execute the "model registration" step:

```
# register model 
model = run.register_model(model_name='my_model', model_path='outputs/my_model.pkl')
print(model.name, model.id, model.version, sep = '\t')
```

However, I haven't created any `run` object as I haven't [executed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/service/tutorial-train-models-with-aml#submit-the-job-to-the-cluster) any experiment for training, I am just starting off with my pickled model.

I also tried to register a model by uploading it via the Azure Portal (see screenshot below), but (as the model file is quite large, I assume) it fails with a `ajax error 413.` as in [Unable to register an ONNX model in azure machine learning service workspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55064123/unable-to-register-an-onnx-model-in-azure-machine-learning-service-workspace).

[image: model registering]

Is there any way to register and then deploy a pretrained pickled mode (without the need of submitting a `run`, if that makes sense)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Model registration can be done with [Model.register](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.model.model?view=azure-ml-py#register-workspace--model-path--model-name--tags-none--properties-none--description-none-), without the need of using a `run` object

```
model = Model.register(model_name='my_model', model_path='my_model.pkl', workspace = ws)
```

for the deployment one can follow steps as outlined in the [Azure ML service doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/service/tutorial-deploy-models-with-aml#deploy-as-a-web-service).

Answer (score 1):

As you have not trained any model on mlflow or run any experiments so you should directly register the saved model through the pickle file.The sklearn library and pickle versions with which the model was saved should be compatible with the current MLflow supported built-in sklearn model flavor.

```
import mlflow

loaded_model = pickle_load(open(filename,'rb')) 

reg_model_name = "Regression" 
mlflow.sklearn.log_model(loaded_model, "sk_learn", serialisation_format="cloudpickle", registered_model_name=reg_model_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also register your model manually in the web portal.