# How can I troubleshoot my Azure ML service deployment?

Tags: python, azure, deployment, azureportal, azure-machine-learning-service

I am trying out [Azure Machine Learning Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/machine-learning-service/) to deploy a ML model as web service.

I have already [registered a model](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55281703/4240413) and now would like to deploy it as web service following the [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/service/tutorial-deploy-models-with-aml#deploy-in-container-instances) using Azure (Python) Notebooks.

The step

```
 service = Webservice.deploy_from_model(my-model-svc',
                                   deployment_config=aciconfig,
                                   models=[model],
                                   image_config=image_config)
```

fails for me with

> Creating image
>   Image creation operation finished for image my-model-svc:5, operation "Succeeded" Creating service
>   Running.
>   FailedACI service creation operation finished, operation
>   "Failed" Service creation polling reached terminal state, current
>   service state: Transitioning Service creation polling reached terminal
>   state, unexpected response received.

Not sure about what could be the root cause, as (AFAIK) I have no ways to access logs of the deployment in Azure portal.

Can someone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that your `init` function is failing. I would first try to isolate the image creation from the image deployment, and just test the image first:

- Create the image first, it's very much ok if do it through the interface
- Pull the image locally with Docker (for this you'll need [Docker](https://www.docker.com) and the [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest) installed):

```python
az acr login -n <container-registry>
docker run -p 8000:5001  <container-registry>.azurecr.io/<image-name>:<image-version>
# basically, the entire image location, see pic below
```

- test the image locally, it listens on the 8000 port:

```
POST http://localhost:8000/score
Content-Type: application/json
```

- if this works deploy it on ACI

`<container-registry>` is the name of the `Container Registry` associated with the ML Workspace, you can also extract it from the image location, taking care to remove everything after the first dot:

[image: image location]

Comment: Thanks!! This allowed me to see the Docker logs and indeed there are some problems there (still have to fix those). It'd be great if errors were a bit more transparent. If you can add in the answer more streamlined ways to access logs/debugging it'd be great, looks like a limitation of Azure ML service as of now to me...

Comment: Welcome! I haven't looked that much into log access, I'll give it a try and see if I find anything.

Comment: I just discovered some useful tips where this is addressed OK: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/service/how-to-troubleshoot-deployment#service-launch-fails

Answer (score 1):

As an additional answer,

```
service.get_logs()
```

is very useful if you deploy from the model without the intermediate docker image.