# Why does my ML model deployment in Azure Container Instance still fail with "current service state: Transitioning"?

Tags: python, docker, deployment, azure-container-instances, azure-machine-learning-service

I am using Azure Machine Learning Service to deploy a ML model as web service.

I [registered a `model`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55281703/4240413) and now would like to deploy it as an ACI web service as in [the guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/service/how-to-deploy-and-where#aci).

To do so I define

```
from azureml.core.webservice import Webservice, AciWebservice
from azureml.core.image import ContainerImage

aciconfig = AciWebservice.deploy_configuration(cpu_cores=4, 
                      memory_gb=32, 
                      tags={"data": "text",  "method" : "NB"}, 
                      description='Predict something')
```

and

```
image_config = ContainerImage.image_configuration(execution_script="score.py", 
                      docker_file="Dockerfile",
                      runtime="python", 
                      conda_file="myenv.yml")
```

and create an image with

```
image = ContainerImage.create(name = "scorer-image",
                      models = [model],
                      image_config = image_config,
                      workspace = ws
                      )
```

Image creation succeeds with

> Creating image Image creation operation finished for image
> scorer-image:5, operation "Succeeded"

Also, troubleshooting the image by running it locally on an Azure VM with

```
sudo docker run -p 8002:5001 myscorer0588419434.azurecr.io/scorer-image:5
```

allows me to run (locally) queries successfully against `http://localhost:8002/score`.

However, deployment with

```
service_name = 'scorer-svc'
service = Webservice.deploy_from_image(deployment_config = aciconfig,
                                        image = image,
                                        name = service_name,
                                        workspace = ws)
```

fails with

> Creating service
> Running.
> FailedACI service creation operation finished, operation "Failed"
> Service creation polling reached terminal state, current service state: Transitioning
> Service creation polling reached terminal state, unexpected response received. Transitioning

I tried setting in the `aciconfig` more generous `memory_gb`, but to no avail: the deployment stays in a *transitioning* state (like in the image below if monitored on the Azure portal):
[image]

Also, running `service.get_logs()` gives me

> WebserviceException: Received bad response from Model Management
> Service: Response Code: 404

What could possibly be the culprit?

Comment: Couple things, what region is your workspace created in? Also, try creating the ACI in a different region using the `location` param in the `deploy_configuration` function. Sometimes different regions can have isolated issues. Also depending what region your workspace is in, `deploy_configuration` will default to that same region if you don't set the param, and ACI isn't supported everywhere. If none of this helps let me know and I will ask who built this package about this exception because I haven't seen it before.

Comment: Hi! I had deployed in West Europe. Looking at `deploy_configuration` actually was a great hint to a solution (see below). Thanks! Error messages were not really helpful here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If ACI deployment fails, one solution is trying to allocate *less* resources, e.g.

```
aciconfig = AciWebservice.deploy_configuration(cpu_cores=1, 
                  memory_gb=8, 
                  tags={"data": "text",  "method" : "NB"}, 
                  description='Predict something')
```

While the error messages thrown are not particularly informative, this is actually clearly stated in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-region-availability):

> When a region is under heavy load, you may experience a failure when
>   deploying instances. To mitigate such a deployment failure, try
>   deploying instances with lower resource settings [...]

The documentation also states which are the maximum values of the CPU/RAM resources available in the different regions (at the time of writing, requiring a deployment with `memory_gb=32` would likely fail in all regions because of insufficient resources).

Upon requiring less resources, deployment should succeed with

> Creating service
>   Running......................................................
>   SucceededACI service creation operation finished, operation
>   "Succeeded" Healthy