# Unable to register Google word2vec model in azure workspace - Azure Machine Learning Services

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I am trying to register the pre-trained [Google word2vec model](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7XkCwpI5KDYNlNUTTlSS21pQmM/edit?usp=sharing)(approx. size 3.5GB) in the azure machine learning workspace. When I tried to register smaller models(approx. size 10MB), I am able to register. However, I am unable to register the pre-trained Google word2vec model.

I tried uploading the model directly in the portal.azure.com, it's throwing AJAX error(maybe because it's a large model). When I tried to register the model through the code(a python script, which connects to the azure workspace), the script keeps executing forever, without any kind of termination and fails to register the model.

Is there a way to register/ upload such large models on Azure machine learning workspace?

Comment: Does the guide at  http://aka.ms/aml-largefiles help to solve the problem?
The Ajax error you get may be similar to the one here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55064123/unable-to-register-an-onnx-model-in-azure-machine-learning-service-workspace also.

Answer (score 1):

As part of registration, all the model files are zipped and uploaded to the blob associated with the workspace. If you are able to register smaller sized models, then it means the plumbing to upload the models is working fine. So the only reason it would take forever is due to upload-to-blob latency. Is your workspace in same region as the client from which you are uploading? If not, then that could be one reason why it is taking forever to upload.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid network bandwidth issues, it usually helps to work from a [Notebook VM](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Educator-Developer-Blog/Azure-Machine-Learning-Notebook-VM/ba-p/683785).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. A 8mb model file works fine with this command:

```
az ml model register -n bigmodel --model-path "models\bigmodelfile.bin" -t "model-deployment\model.json"
```

However I get an OperationTimedout when I try it with a 900meg model from my local machine.

I suspect the solution is to upload it to a blob in the same region as your AMLS with Storage Explorer and and then mount it as a datastore file as per this article. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/service/how-to-save-write-experiment-files#limits

Then AZML can pull it from the blob directly.